# generating swipe objects with swipe.js

Tags: javascript, swipe

Using swipe.js (www.swipejs.com), I'd like to attach it to generated DIVs.

In a Javscript loop, I am doing the following:

```
$.each( data, function( i, item)  {

resultHtml = '<div id="swipe-div-' + item.i  + '" class="swipe">' +
'<ul>' +
'<li>Test 1<li>' +
'<li>Test 2<li>' +
'</ul></div>' +
'<a href="#" onclick="swipe-div-' + item.i + '.prev();return false;">prev</a>' +
'<a href="#" onclick="swipe-div-' + item.i + '.next();return false;">next</a>';

$('div#results').append( resultHtml );

new Swipe(document.getElementById('swipe-div-' + item.i));

}
```

: I am having trouble with my prev and next links. I suspect it may have to do with the following line:

new Swipe(document.getElementById('swipe-div-' + item.i));

which is not initializing the swipe object properly.

When I click on prev or next, I get the following error in the Javascript console:

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, since nobody has answered this, I figured out how to solve my own problem:

Rather than generating and appending text strings, I just created the structure using document.createElement and appendChild.

At the end of creating the structure, I added in the following code:

```
var slider = new Swipe(document.getElementById('result-' + item.i));
clickPrev(slider, prev);
clickNext(slider, next);
```

and added the following functions:

```
function clickNext(swipeObj, link) {
    link.onclick = function () {
        swipeObj.next();
        return false;
    }
}

function clickPrev(swipeObj, link) {
    link.onclick = function () {
        swipeObj.prev();
        return false;
    }
}
```

It was easier to follow this way and works great now.